# Convert columns to rows by index value with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe structured like this:

| Name | Identifier | Tags_0_Value | Tags_1_Value | Tags_2_Value | Tags_3_Value | Tags_4_Value | Tags_5_Value | Tags_6_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bottle Nose Well | 1345 |  | A- Groundwater Aquifer | WL - Water Level Network | 104 - Area Wide Map | 110 - Area Network | 114 - Area Wide Monitoring |  |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | A - Groundwater Aquifer | HR - Domestic Wells | 15 - Baylor County Well Survey | 20- Data collection | 3 - Water Level Measurable | 6 - Onsite | 9 - Water Quality |

but I want to collapse the columns starting with "Tags" into a single column and append every value to a row indexed by the Name/Identifier, like this:

| Name | Identifier | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bottle Nose Well | 1345 | A- Groundwater Aquifer |
| Bottle Nose Well | 1345 | WL - Water Level Network |
| Bottle Nose Well | 1345 | 104 - Area Wide Map |
| Bottle Nose Well | 1345 | 110 - Area Network |
| Bottle Nose Well | 1345 | 114 - Area Wide Monitoring |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | A - Groundwater Aquifer |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | HR - Domestic Wells |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | 15 - Baylor County Well Survey |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | 20- Data collection |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | 3 - Water Level Measurable |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | 6 - Onsite |
| BMOs Adventure | 3745 | 9 - Water Quality |

I've tried the transpose and pivot functions in Pandas, but already know that's not I need.

Comment: `df.melt(['Name','Identifier'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `set_index` + `stack`:

```
out = df.set_index(['Name','Identifier']).stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index(name='Tags')
```

Output:

```
                Name  Identifier                            Tags
0   Bottle Nose Well        1345          A- Groundwater Aquifer
1   Bottle Nose Well        1345        WL - Water Level Network
2   Bottle Nose Well        1345             104 - Area Wide Map
3   Bottle Nose Well        1345              110 - Area Network
4   Bottle Nose Well        1345      114 - Area Wide Monitoring
5     BMOs Adventure        3745         A - Groundwater Aquifer
6     BMOs Adventure        3745             HR - Domestic Wells
7     BMOs Adventure        3745  15 - Baylor County Well Survey
8     BMOs Adventure        3745             20- Data collection
9     BMOs Adventure        3745      3 - Water Level Measurable
10    BMOs Adventure        3745                      6 - Onsite
11    BMOs Adventure        3745               9 - Water Quality
```